# Redeem deal, removing tableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In my app, I have *app deals* in a UITableViewController. Each tableviewcell is a deal. When the user taps on the cell, it follows a push segue to a UIViewController where he/she can redeem the deal.

When the user taps on the redeem button, I want the previous tableviewcell to be removed. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, very possible and rather simple.
use global variable to represent your list of deals, most likely it's a stand alone class, which is called (but not present) in your UITableViewController...

**How to do so:**
Set-up a data structure class with a mutable array representing the list of "deals". From everywhere in the app you can request the list or delete elements from it mostly using singleton or any other global variables method - see more here: [Don't understand global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910052/dont-understand-global-variables/23910519#23910519)

This is also good practice in general, separating your data from viewcontrollers and UI. (see also: Model–view–controller (MVC))

Comment: Great suggestion, but I am not sure this would work. Each deal is segued by the index path, not by its own cell. The redeem button will not know which deal to remove from the mutable array. Is there a way I could remove the indexPath.row that I selected? @chewy

Comment: yes, also hold a small array of indexes related to a key in your main array.
therefore you will pass the indexpath to the index array and in return it will give you the object you are looking for. very much like a numeric index in a book.